# Postgres Connection Issue with Connection URL

Tags: postgresql, configuration, psql, configure

I am trying to connect to pgAdmin using my psql connection url:

```
postgres://michaelr:password@localhost:5432/testdb
```

I am getting:

```
1. url: "unable to connect to resource: ensure the database is reachable at the specified URL and with the provided credentials"
```

I have configured my PostgreSQL.conf file to read:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

I am thinking that port 5432 is not open to all traffic because when running "netstat -an | grep 5432" I see it can only locally connect but not through pgAdmin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) Can you connect to the database using `psql` using the shown connection paramters? 2) What is the third party app? 3) What is Postgres version? 4) What does the Postgres log show? 5) Version information should always be included for software mentioned. Add answers as update to question.

Comment: I can but only locally. After running "netstat -an | grep 5432" I see I can only access this locally. I have opened those ports up in the conf files but for some reason it is not taking even after I restart my postgresql.

Comment: 1) You have not answered all the questions 2) You did not add the information to the original question as requested. 3) Is the issue you are trying to connect from a remote machine back to this server?. Remember update your question.

Comment: The question has now changed. I will update the post. I am now realizing that port 5432 is not open to all traffic so I cannot connect to it.

1) I can connect using psql on my CLI but not with pgAdmin
2) pgAdmin
3) 14
4) did not check

Comment: 1) pgAdmin != Postgres server. So you are trying to connect PgAdmin to a Postgres server. 2) Again, are you trying to connect from a remote machine?

Comment: 1) yeah, I am trying to connect to my Postgres DB with pgAdmin 2) I am not. I am just trying to connect with pgAdmin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245520/discussion-between-michael-ryan-and-adrian-klaver).